# solubility of nonlinear overdetermined PDE for holonomic scaling of a frame

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, nonlinear-system

This question is essentially a tweak of [under what conditions can orthogonal vector fields make curvilinear coordinate system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1270888/44161) .

Suppose we have a frame of vector fields $\nu_i$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. As discussed in the linked question, these $\nu_i$ will (at least locally) form the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ of a coordinate system on $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff they commute pairwise.

Suppose that the $\nu_i$ do not commute. When is it possible (say, locally) to find $n$ non-vanishing functions $f_i$ such that

$$[f_i\nu_i,f_j\nu_j]=0?$$

This collection of equations can be regarded as an overdetermined system of $\frac{1}{2}n^2(n-1)$ nonlinear PDE. What is the solubility condition for this system?

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of of generality, we consider strictly positive functions $ f_i := \exp  {g^i} $ and slove the problem for functions $g^i$.
After calculation, the equation $[\exp g^i \cdot v_i, \exp g^j \cdot v_j] = 0$
is the same as
$$ [v_i, v_j] = v_j g^i \cdot v_i - v_i g^j \cdot v_j .$$

Therefore, when the given involutive frame has dimension 2, i.e.,
$$ [v_1, v_2] = \alpha \cdot v_1 - \beta \cdot v_2 $$
for two smooth functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we only need to solve the following two independent differential equations:
$$ v_2 g^1 = \alpha,\quad v_1 g^2 = \beta.$$
Locally, this is always possible.

For involutive frame of higher dimension, we should **necessarily** have that
each two vector fields are involutive
from our rewriting of the equations.
In this case, we denote by $\Gamma^i_j$ the corresponding coefficients (they are smooth functions):
$$ [v_i, v_j] = \Gamma^i_j \cdot v_i - \Gamma_i^j \cdot v_j, \quad i \neq j. $$
And we then need to solve the overdetermined system for each $g^i$ :
$$ v_j g^i = \Gamma^i_j, \quad j \neq i.$$
The following **sufficient** condition for the existence of $g^i$ comes from the Frobenius theorem, stated as Theorem 19.27 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*,
$$ v_k \Gamma^i_j - v_j \Gamma^i_k = \Gamma^k_j \cdot \Gamma^i_k - \Gamma^j_k \cdot \Gamma^i_j , \quad  \forall k \neq i, \, j \neq i,$$
which is eq.(19.10) in the book.
It is obvious that the above condition is **also necessary** as $ v_k(v_j g^i) - v_j(v_k g^i) = [v_k, v_j] g^i $.